# Calculating speed of an object at the bottom of a curved slope?

Tags: energy, speed

Say you had a slope and it was like a ski slope that started shallow, got steeper and shallow again, and you knew that the top of the slope was a certain height vertically upwards from the bottom of the slope.

How would you calculate the speed of an object as it passes the bottom point of the slope given only the vertical height and mass of the object, assuming no energy losses?

Comment: hint: energy is conserved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to know the difference in height between the starting point and the end point in order to know the gain in potential energy, $mgh$. Since you stated "assuming no energy losses", all of that energy is converted to kinetic energy $\frac12 m v^2$.

Set the two equal - that is, put $mgh = \frac12 mv^2$, and solve for $v$. It turns out that the answer is independent of the mass $m$ (it appears on both sides of the equation, and so it cancels). This makes sense - if somebody is skiing down a hill, they go the same speed whether you do the calculation separately for their left leg, their right leg, or their entire body.